# how to use ffmpeg with node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, backend

Hiiii. I would like to use ffmpeg for this project ([click to check out](https://github.com/Jes015/ScreenCapture)). I tried to use wasm but it was too slow. So i'm making a back app with nestjs and nodejs for this. I want to question: What is the better to do? Should i use bindings? or what should i use?. (Please, i already look up this topic and i know that there is a library called "ffmpeg" in npm, if you don't know about how to work  correctly please, just don't reply)

I tried with ffmpeg.wasm, but it was too slow. So i'm making a back.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have use ffmpeg for genrate thumbnail from video which is working for me

```
const ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path;
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

const inputVideoPath = folderpath;
const thumbnailTime = 5;

ffmpeg(inputVideoPath)
  .seekInput(thumbnailTime)
  .frames(1)
  .size(`150x80`)
  .output(outputThumbnailPath)
  .on("end", () => {})
  .run();
```